# Microsoft PowerBI with Hortonworks Hive/HBase/Spark Integration

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, powerbi

I'm thrilled with Microsoft's offering with PowerBI but still not able to find any possible direct way to integrate with my Hortonworks Hadoop cluster.
I went through the tutorials and found two things:

- PowerBI can fetch data from HDInsights Azure cluster using thrift, if that's possible then is it possible to connect with any other Hadoop distro to connect to it as well?
- We can connect using ODBC driver which is offered by Simba Technologies but I was wondering if it's possible to connect using Apache Phoenix drivers which offer JDBC drivers for HBase?

Appreciate your thoughts/suggestions/help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice Machine has an ODBC driver for retrieving data that is stored ultimately in HBase.

Checkout the ODBC driver on this page..

http://community.splicemachine.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to connect Power BI to other Hadoop distros via ODBC driver e.g. http://www.simba.com/webinar/powerbi-demo/

Power BI doesn't support JDBC drivers, but if you are interested in testing ODBC driver for Phoenix please contact [Simba Technologies](http://www.simba.com/contact-us/).